# Deploy Prometheus to Cloud Foundry

Tags: go, cloud-foundry, prometheus

I want to deploy Prometheus to Cloud Foundry without using Docker container. When I try to deploy it with the standard Cloud Foundry Go Buildpack I get the following error:

```
can't load package: package prometheus: no buildable Go source files in /tmp/tmp.vv4iyDzMvE/.go/src/prometheus
```

Which somehow makes sense, because there are actually no sources in the  root directory and the project is compiled with the Prometheus utility tool.

Is there any way to deploy Prometheus to Cloud Foundry, like using another Buildpack or something?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, but (just today) came up with a slightly different solution, that seemed easier to me.

I used the prometheus-2.2.1-linux-amd64 binary build.

I modified the **prometheus.yml** to use the default port 8080 as a target (last line):

```
    # my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080'] ###### Only changed this line
```

Then I added a **manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- name: prometheus
  instances: 1
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git
  command: ./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml --web.listen-address=:8080 --web.enable-admin-api
  memory: 1024M
  random-route: true
```

That is using the binary-buildpack, and tells prometheus to startup the server listening on port 8080.

2 files changes and this:

```
cf push
```

Now I have prometheus running in my space on Pivotal Web Services.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is a TSDB. And it is intended to consume gigabytes and gigabytes of data.

On a Cloud Foundry platform, you are limited by available resources. 
So, why deploy Prometheus to Cloud Foundry?

Why not spin up a standalone `bosh director` and deploy Prometheus through the director as a Bosh deployment, and a standalone. Then inject it as a CUPS into Cloud Foundry?

I am just curious and trying to understand the use case.

Comment: Are those rhetorical questions? If not, they belong in comments to the question - [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Otherwise, it works better to state them as facts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after digging around a bit I got the whole thing working as follows

**manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- name: prometheus
  instances: 1
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack.git
  command: prometheus
  env:
    GOPACKAGENAME: github.com/prometheus/prometheus
    GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC: github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/prometheus
  memory: 1000M
```

BUT in order to listen on the right port, the only solution I could find is adding the following to the `cmd/prometheus/config.go` file to the beginning of the `init()` function

```
port := ":9090"
if s := os.Getenv("PORT"); s != "" {
    port = ":"+s
}
```

and then changing the following part (also in the `init()` function)

```
cfg.fs.StringVar(
    &cfg.web.ListenAddress, "web.listen-address", ":9090",
    "Address to listen on for the web interface, API, and telemetry.",
)
```

to

```
cfg.fs.StringVar(
    &cfg.web.ListenAddress, "web.listen-address", port,
    "Address to listen on for the web interface, API, and telemetry.",
)
```

After that you can simply deploy the application with `cf push` and everything should work as a charm